# Solutions to an equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

How many solutions exist to the equation $|x|=|2x - 1|$?

I just don't know where to start from, so I humbly need your help.

Comment: $|x|=|y|$ iff $x=\pm y$

Comment: Split into the cases of $[x<0]$, $[0\leq x<\frac12]$ and $[\frac12\leq x]$.

Comment: Suggest a sketch...

Answer (score 1):

Hnt: you must do case work:
a) $$x\geq \frac{1}{2}$$ and we have to solve $$x=2x-1$$
b) $$0\le x <\frac{1}{2}$$ thus we get $$x=-2x+1$$
c)$$x<0$$ and we have to solve $$-x=-2x+1$$

Comment: Thanks Dr. Graubner.
Could you please explain further and moreover I don't get what you mean by "case work".

Best Wishes,
Obed.